# Class Member Variable not Saving State

Tags: c++

I'm new to C/C++, so people excuse me if this is a noob question.

I have a controller class, which has a private member variable which is a `vector<Contact> contacts`. The class has methods which allow us to change the state of this vector (standard CRUD operations).

The class has a public method called `get_contacts()` which returns this private vector of objects:

```
std::vector<Contact> Contacts_Controller::get_contacts() const {
    return this->contacts;
}
```

I have a method which adds the `contact` to this private vector via `push_back()`. The issue is that if the `add_contact()` method uses the accessor method, then the class variable does not get updated:

```
void Contacts_Controller::add_contact(const Contact &contact) {
    this->get_contacts().push_back(contact);
}
```

I *assume* this is a memory issue, perhaps I have some issues with my use of `const` or I'm not correctly using references, because the following code works exactly as expected:

```
void Contacts_Controller::add_contact(const Contact &contact) {
    this->contacts.push_back(contact);
}
```

Using either method won't return any errors, but if I then request the vector of contacts after using the first method it'll be empty, whereas the second method correctly adds data to the vector.

Again, sorry if this is a noob question, but I'm completely stumped, and I wouldn't know what to search for! How would I fix this referencing issue?

Comment: You are returning the vector by value in `get_contacts` so `push_back` is modifying a local copy that gets destroyed at the end of the statement.

Comment: What exactly is C/C++?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am new to developing code in the C and C++ programming languages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The class has a public method called get_contacts() which returns this private vector of objects"

Nope, it returns a copy. You need to return by reference to get the actual member:

```
std::vector<Contact>& Contacts_Controller::get_contacts(){
    return this->contacts;
}
```

**Note** that I removed the `const`, otherwise you'd have to mark the return as `const` also and you wouldn't be able to modify it.

Comment: Haha that fixed it! Thanks, could you explain why I need to remove `const`? My understanding is that a method should use it if it does not need to modify member variables?

Comment: @Cristian all the member variables become `const` inside a `const` function (including `contacts`) and you can't (shouldn't) return a non-`const` ref to a `const` variable.

Comment: @Cristian You are completely right, a method should use `const` if it does not need to modify member variables. But in your example, you do need to modify it, so the `const` has to be removed. Bear in mind that you can overload your getters, too, so you can declare both a `const` and a non-const getter.

Comment: @blackbird Thanks for the explanation. I don't see though how the method is modifying anything as it's just returning data?

Comment: @Cristian The method itself does not modify it, but the caller of the method should be able to modify it. Try `std::vector<Contact>& Contacts_Controller::get_contacts() const {
    return this->contacts;
}` *with* the `const` at the end and see it fail to compile :)

Comment: @blackbird It suddenly makes more sense ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cristian technically, it doesn't mean that you can't modify members, but more. It means that `this` can't be used in a non-const context (which implies you can't modify members). Returning a non-const reference to a member would implicitly attempt to convert it to a non-const from a `const`.

Comment: Note however that a const state is relatively "weak" when it comes to member pointers and references. You cannot modify the pointer, but you change what it points to. References can never be reseated anyway, and the constness is not propagated.

If your class is implemented via pImpl or you have a pointer to your data member (even if your class is responsible for it), that pointer can be returned by a const function even when you intend to modify the underlying data.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore you can emulate propagating the constness. e.g. if your class uses a pImpl you can make your methods const when and only when they are const in the pImpl, although it would compile if you made all of them const.

In any case, I wasn't saying you cannot implement your classes to propagate constness, I was just saying that the compiler doesn't do it for you.

You need to beware of "copying to remove constness" if you are holding shared pointers and try to propagate the constness into them.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your function is returning the vector by value, which means the calling function gets a copy.

When you call push_back() on it, only the copy gets the extra member.

Your function could return a reference. Then your user can call push_back(). If it is a member variable of your class and you are returning a non-const reference (which you must to allow the modification) your function will probably also be non-const.

Thus:

```
std::vector<Contact> & Contacts_Controller::get_contacts()  // not const
  {  return this->contacts; }
```

You can also have a read-only version, as an overload.

```
std::vector<Contact> const & Contacts_Controller::get_contacts() const
  {  return this->contacts; }
```

This version allows read-only access to the contacts and can also be a const member function.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `get_contacts`,  you return a copy of `this->contacts`. If you want to share a vector, either return a reference to it (but you must be sure that your reference will stay valid so your class instance won't be moved or copied), or use a smart pointer to dynamically allocate the space for your vector and extend its lifetime until the last reference to it has been destructed. In this case use a member with type `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Contact> >`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you provide an example on how to fix this?

Comment: If you want to share a vector, either return a reference to it (but you must be sure that your reference will stay valid), or use a smart pointer to dynamically allocate the space for your vector and extend its lifetime until the last reference to it has been destructed. In this case use a member with type `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Contact> >` .